# How do I specify generic lifetime for function pointer parameters?

Tags: rust, lifetime

**Background**

Closures in Rust have anonymous type and cannot be referred to as a known concrete type. However [from Feb 2017](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39817), all non-capturing closures can be converted to anonymous functions and have the same type as a function pointer.

I wanted to create a type that standardizes curried closures. If we have a function `fn(T1, T2, ...) -> R` we can have a special type that is `FnXXX(T2, ...) -> R` (replace `XXX` with  or `Mut` or `Once`, or `Box`). They can then be used inside containers without involving dynamic dispatch.

**Attempt for `FnOnce`**

The following works:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
#![feature(fn_traits)]

struct Curry0<T, R> {
    f: fn(T) -> R,
    v: T,
}
impl<T, R> FnOnce<()> for Curry0<T, R> {
    type Output = R;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _: ()) -> R {
        (self.f)(self.v)
    }
}

fn curry<T, R>(f: fn(T) -> R, v: T) -> impl FnOnce() -> R {
    Curry0 { f: f, v: v }
}

fn main() {
    curry(|s| println!("{}", s), "Hello, World!")()
}
```

However, I am not able to add the following:

```
impl<'a, T, R> FnMut<()> for Curry0<&'a mut T, R> {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, _: ()) -> R {
        (self.f)(self.v)
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
  --> src/main.rs:16:18
   |
16 |         (self.f)(self.v)
   |                  ^^^^^^
   |
note: ...the reference is valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 14:1...
  --> src/main.rs:14:1
   |
14 | impl<'a, T, R> FnMut<()> for Curry0<&'a mut T, R> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 15:5
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 | /     extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, _: ()) -> R {
16 | |         (self.f)(self.v)
17 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

My understanding is that for this to work, `call_mut` must take care that `&mut self` only lives for the function itself, and so if `f` returns something that refers to `v`'s inside, it will be invalid.

**Attempt for `FnMut`**

To work with `FnMut` rather than `FnOnce` above I wrote:

```
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]
#![feature(fn_traits)]

struct Curry0Mut<'a, 'b, T, R>
where
    T: 'a,
    R: 'b,
{
    f: fn(&mut T) -> R,
    v: &'a mut T,
    _l: std::marker::PhantomData<&'b ()>,
}
impl<'a, 'b, T, R> FnOnce<()> for Curry0Mut<'a, 'b, T, R> {
    type Output = R;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, _: ()) -> R {
        (self.f)(self.v)
    }
}
impl<'a, 'b, T, R> FnMut<()> for Curry0Mut<'a, 'b, T, R>
where
    T: 'a,
    R: 'b,
{
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, _: ()) -> R {
        (self.f)(self.v)
    }
}

fn curry<'a, T, R>(f: fn(&mut T) -> R, v: &'a mut T) -> impl FnMut() -> R + 'a {
    Curry0Mut {
        f: f,
        v: v,
        _l: std::marker::PhantomData,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = "Hello, World".to_owned();
    curry(|s| println!("{}", s), &mut v)();
}
```

This is more complicated and sadly we have two structs for just slightly different usage. When I looked closer at the change I have to make here, I figured out that `f` is actually a generic function on its parameter's lifetime, and `T`'s lifetime is independent to this. We also have to make sure `R` does not live longer than the closure itself, so its lifetime has to be encoded inside the closure.

I will not go into detail for `Fn` as it is similar. Only to note that this makes it worse as we need another variation of `Curry0`, because `&mut T` is not `&T`.

**The Question**

Is it possible to express the fact that `v` has a different lifetime expectation than `f`s parameter?

For example, how to write something like:

```
struct Curry0<'a, 'b, T, R>
where
    R: 'b,
{
    f: fn(T) -> R, //T have generic lifetime
    v: T,          //T: 'a
    _a: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a ()>,
    _b: std::marker::PhantomData<&'b ()>,
}
```